# How to build single module in multi module android app with jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, android-gradle-plugin

I have an android app with 3 modules using gradle. Common, user, admin. Both user and admin use common module (compile project(':common')).
I need to build separately user and admin module.
Currently I have in Jenkins tasks: clean assemble test. That builds both admin and user modules into separate apks. How to trigger that just one is build ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify specific task which you want to build.For example your user app has module name as user you can use

> gradlew :user

instead of clean assemble test which tries to build everything

Comment: Wouldn't this build an AAR and not build an APK like the question is asking for?

Comment: @Ryan I guess user is an application so you will get an apk.I guess in your application common is library module.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sintax:

```
:{module}:{task}
```

In your case you should enter:

```
:user:assemble
```

You can find the exact task name in "Event Log" when building the project in Android Studio (usually down-right position in Android Studio). I usually copy from there and paste in Jenkins. :)